# SQL Server - logic to allow me to do a calculation in the where statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have searched for an answer for ages with no luck for my particular problem.

I have been asked to create a script to extract data for a mail-merge.  Our billing team need to identify users who we have sent final warning notices to but have still not paid their bills.

The biggest challenge that I have been unable to overcome is that some of the customers may have done one of the following:

1. not made any payments for the outstanding amount
2. paid the outstanding amount in full in one payment
3. paid the outstanding amount in full with multiple payments
4. paid part of the outstanding amount in one or multiple payments

The data that was used to generate the final warning notices is in a table with the outstanding amount appearing as a positive number, and any payments that have been made are in a different table as a negative number.

In my query identifying customers from scenario 1 and 2 would be fairly easy to identify, but 3 and 4 are causing me headaches.  I had the idea of adding the outstanding amount to a sum of any payments made.  If the sum total is > 0 then the customer has not paid enough to cover the outstanding amount. I have developed a sub-query to get a total of all payments made after a certain date but I can't get the query to add that to the outstanding amount and then check to see if the balance is greater than 0.  Error I get is "Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery."

Can someone recommend a different approach to this query?

```
SELECT 
    finalwarning.table_no AS [Property No], 
    finalwarning.value_1 AS [Arrears Balance], 
    finalwarning.date_1 AS [Notice Date] 
FROM 
    finalwarning  
WHERE
    finalwarning.table_no = 172030 
    AND finalwarning.ref_3 = 'Final' 
    AND ((SELECT 
              CASE
                 WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                              FROM paymentsmade 
                              WHERE PROPERTY_NO = 1234 
                                AND TRANSACTION_DESC = 'Receipt' 
                                AND TRANSACTION_DATE > '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000' 
                             GROUP BY TRANSACTION_DESC) 
                   THEN (SELECT SUM(amount) 
                         FROM paymentsmade 
                         WHERE paymentsmade.PROPERTY_NO = 1234 
                           AND paymentsmade.TRANSACTION_DESC = 'Receipt' 
                           AND paymentsmade.TRANSACTION_DATE > '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000' 
                         GROUP BY paymentsmade.TRANSACTION_DESC)    
                   ELSE '0' 
              END) + finalwarning.value_1) < 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CTE are our friends and really help get the hard work done for us and allow for easier writing of the core SQL.  The example below takes your structure and applies the concept of a payments CTE which will aggregate payments by property no and provide for all of the calculations you need to perform in your evaluation.  I was uncertain about how the date came into play and the join might be wrong because there were 2 different numbers provided for property_no in the example but I assumed they were one and the same.

```
WITH paymentCTE  (property_no, amount, transaction_desc, cntpayments) 
as
(select property_no, sum(amount) as amount, transaction_desc, count(*) 
from paymentsmade
where TRANSACTION_DATE > > '2017-05-01 00:00:00.000' 
group by property_no, transaction_desc
)

SELECT fw.table_no AS [Property No]
, fw.value_1 AS [Arrears Balance]
, fw.date_1 AS [Notice Date]
, coalesce(p1.amount,0) as [Payments Made]
, fw.value_1+coalesce(p1.amount,0) as [Outstanding Balance]
, coalesce(p1.cntpayments, 0) as [Number of Payments]
FROM finalwarning fw 
left outer join paymentCTE p1 
on fw.table_no = p1.property_no 
and p1.Transaction_desc = 'Receipt'
WHERE p1.cntpayments is null
or (coalesce(p1.cntpayments, 0) = 1 and fw.value_1 + coalesce(p1.amount,0) = 0)
or (coalesce(p1.cntpayments, 0) > 1 and fw.value_1 + coalesce(p1.amount,0) = 0)
or (coalesce(p1.cntpayments, 0) > 0 and fw.value_1 + coalesce(p1.amount,0)<> 0)
```

Comment: You should make an effort to be **consistent** with how you write the SQL keywords - *either* write them in all UPPERCASE (SELECT, FROM), or write them in all lowercase (select, from), or in mixed case (Select, From) - but please **pick one style** and then **stick to it** - don't mix all of them together!

Comment: Thanks Louise, I have never used CTE before but I think that now it is my friend too  :)